# How do I add html tags in jquery plugins?

Tags: laravel, jquery-plugins

I am doing the live search using the jquery plugins. When I tried to search that doesn't exist, it only shows the table. I would like to put some message "No result found" if it doesnt exist. The question is how can I add message "No result found"

Note: In my codes I add some validation, the user need input minimum of 3 characters

```
/**
    **options to have following keys:
        **searchText: this should hold the value of search text
        **searchPlaceHolder: this should hold the value of search input box placeholder
**/
(function($)
{
    $.fn.tableSearch = function(options)
    {
        if(!$(this).is('table'))
        {
            return;
        }
        var tableObj = $(this),

            searchText = (options.searchText)?options.searchText:'Search: ',
            searchPlaceHolder = (options.searchPlaceHolder)?options.searchPlaceHolder:'',
            divObj = $('<div style="font-size:20px;">'+searchText+'</div><br /><br />'),
            inputObj = $('<input style="min-width:25%;max-width:50%;margin-left:1%" type="text" placeholder="'+searchPlaceHolder+'" />'),
            caseSensitive = (options.caseSensitive===true)?true:false,
            searchFieldVal = '',
            pattern = '';
            inputObj.off('keyup').on('keyup', function(){
            searchFieldVal = $(this).val();
            if(searchFieldVal.length == 0) 
            { 
                tableObj.find('tbody tr').show(); 
            }
            else if(searchFieldVal.length >= 3)
            {
                pattern = (caseSensitive)?RegExp(searchFieldVal):RegExp(searchFieldVal, 'i');
                tableObj.find('tbody tr').hide().each(function()
                {
                    var currentRow = $(this);
                    currentRow.find('td').each(function()
                    {
                        var result = "No result";
                        $("tbody tr").append(result);
                        if(pattern.test($(this).html()))
                        {

                            currentRow.show();
                            return false;
                        }

                    });
                });
            }
        });
        tableObj.before(divObj.append(inputObj));
        return tableObj;
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Why does this have the laravel tag? Show your html and we can give you a better answer.

Comment: Sir, im doing it in laravel. Should I post my view also?

Comment: Yes post your view. And there is nothing related to Laravel in your problem so having the Laravel tag is misleading.

Comment: Sir, i included the Laravel tag is because i am doing it in the laravel framework..

Answer (score 0):

Here into JQ plugin(Posted at your question), the handler for empty result is exist. See piece of code from it.

```
else if(searchFieldVal.length >= 3)
{
    pattern = (caseSensitive)?RegExp(searchFieldVal):RegExp(searchFieldVal, 'i');
    tableObj.find('tbody tr').hide().each(function()
    {
        var currentRow = $(this);
        currentRow.find('td').each(function()
        {
            var result = "No result";
            $("tbody tr").append(result);
            if(pattern.test($(this).html()))
            {

                currentRow.show();
                return false;
            }

        });
    });
}
```

Paraphrase you mistaken at your end. Re check it.

Comment: Pardon me sir but I dont get it.. The variable result will be show when there's no result found